# Newline without indent

Tags: jasper-reports, indentation

I set `isStretchWithOverflow` of `textField` to true, so that the whole string would appear. That works fine, but the indent of the second line is not like the first line. Actually, there is no indent in the second line at all. Take a look at the second and third entries:
[image]

this is the textField:

```
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
        <reportElement uuid="08242c22-8c1f-4c9a-90c9-0bc7cc9019d3" style="Sans_Normal" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="300" height="15" backcolor="#E5ECF9"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Description}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

I want ***integration release.*** just under ***this document ...***. Same for the third entry.
I tried to set/change some properties with iReport but couldn't found any to fix this.

---

update

I changed the textField to:

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="7399fe90-aea8-48d6-b2b2-9435f8d80198" style="Sans_Normal" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="300" height="15" backcolor="#E5ECF9"/>
            <box leftPadding="-10"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Description}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

but this just shift the whole entries to the left.

Comment: What creates the indent in the first line?

Comment: @justSaid Did you set padding (***leftPadding***)?

Comment: Don't know. I added the textfield

Comment: Can you post the snippet from the *jrxml* file with *textField* declaration?

Comment: @AlexK, yeah, I just edited my question

Comment: @justSaid Can you additionally post the style *Sans_Normal* declaration?

Comment: `<style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="Serif" fontSize="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>`

Comment: @justSaid Both looks normal. Did you try to export report to *csv* or *txt*? In this case you can check the text (from ***Description*** filed) for CR and other symbols

Comment: @AlexK yeah, I just export the report to csv

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34628/discussion-between-justsaid-and-alex-k)

Comment: @AlexK- Can you give any hint on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551095/indetation-in-generated-pdf-using-jasperreports?