# Keep indentation for new lines in a <li> tag

Tags: jasper-reports

I've created a Text Field in iReport with this expression:

```
"<ul><li>asdf asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd fasdfasd fghfdghd fghdfghd fghdfghd fghdfgh</li></ul>"
```

I set "Markup" to "html".

The text is too long to fit in one row, so it breaks. This is totally fine. The problem is, that the new line has no indentation.

What it looks like, when I run the report as PDF:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try putting `list-style: disc outside none;` in `ul` style.

Comment: Hi, how can I apply CSS to an element in JasperReports?

Comment: I never used JasperRecords.

Can you do this? 
<ul style ='list-style: disc outside none;'> ... </ul>

Comment: Sorry! Something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551095/indentation-in-generated-pdf-using-jasperreports

Comment: Yeah, but it does not work with negative values for some reason. You've never used JasperReports you say? That's something to be proud of.