# List indentation on jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, indentation, export-to-pdf

I'm receiving long text paragraphs via JSON to fill my reports. These text are in html format, son my textfield looks like this:

```
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="60" y="1" width="490" height="9" forecolor="#1F497D" uuid="6448707a-6f36-4bef-96a1-6bc7634e72c3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="34deaa54-ac6e-42dd-8c82-c125d6810c22"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

The problem is about lists and the indentation. I found some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551095/indentation-in-generated-pdf-using-jasperreports/26583760#26583760) using negative values for the first line indent, but my problem is that I didn't know where I will have a html tag list or not.

This is the output when get a list is like:

1.- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

And I need to indent like this:

1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
   ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
   and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

How can I align this to the right? Are there any hack? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating this text with HTML, seemingly you should be able to use CSS.

If so, then the CSS property [text-indent](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp) could be a good quick hack for this purpose. If you're able to add a class name to the field you want indented, then simply do something like the following:

```
.myClass {
    text-indent: 85px;
}
```

or even, simply use margin-left:

```
.myClass {
    margin-left: 85px;
}
```

If you're not able to use CSS, then as a last resort (although not recommended), you an surround your intended-to-be indented text in `<blockquote>` tags. If even that doesn't seem right, then you can insert 4 empty space characters, `&nbsp;`, before each line of your text. So if you had an incoming string, you can use some JavaScript like this:

```
let tab = "";
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) tab += "&nbsp;"
myString.split("\n").map(x=>tab + x).join("<br>");
```

If you're not able to use JavaScript for whatever reason, then if you have any control of where that text is coming from, you can rewrite the same code above in whatever language you are using.

Comment: Thanks! 
But unfortunately there is no way to use css class, or inline style to modify the elements layout. It only allows to use with CSS styles like bold, italic, color, but nothing about layout. About jasvascript, it's the same, no way to use it as far as I know. 
Now I'm working with the core library trying to modify it to detect lists and add the correct indentation. Thanks!

Comment: @Pipeline OK, but where is "<![CDATA[$F{text}]]>" coming from? Do you have a way to modify $[F{text}] on the server side? If so you can split each line by \n and add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line